# WTForms obj=sqlalchemy.Model not working?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm using Flask, with SQLAlchemy and WTForms. Here are my snippets :

```
class AccountForm(Form):
    name     = StringField(validators=[validators.Optional(),], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    email    = StringField(validators=[validators.Optional(), validators.Email()], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    password = PasswordField(validators=[validators.Optional()], filters = [lambda x: x or None])


class Account(Model):
    __tablename__   = 'accounts'

    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name            = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    email           = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password        = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True, default=None)
```

I then make a PUT request to `/account/` with only the `name` parameter :

```
@app.route("/account/", methods=['PUT',])
@authenticated
def update():
    # g.account contains the instance of the Model Account
    form = AccountForm(request.form, obj=g.account)


    # form.email.data is empty !
    # It should be set at the value from the Account model ?!

    if not form.validate():
        return form.errors_as_json()

    form.email.data is None # True
```

I followed the documentation, tried few alternatives (`populate_obj`, etc) without any luck, I can't load the data from the model in the form!

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you passing in `request.form` AND the model instance? To populate a form, WTForms first checks if formdata is provided, then it will check `obj`. Remove `request.form` and try it again.

Comment: No. I finally analyzed the code, and the logic is respected : it firts take the parameter from the `formdata` parameter (first param), and if not present, take the value from the `obj` parameter. The problem lie outside : In the StringField (for example), the `process_formdata` return the value from `formdata` if present, or **an empty string** else. Since it returns an empty string, WTForms doesn't go further to check in `obj` ... hence my issue here.

Comment: Having the same issue. @CyrilN. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Yes and no. I couldn't make it work so I created an extended form class (all my forms like `AccountForm` extends a BaseForm I creeated) that contains a `get_as_dict` method. Then, I did the same with all my models to get an dict to create/update it. And that way it works.